# How can I check that two records contain the same information in 3 specific fields?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views, django-orm

What I'm trying to do is put people in random groups, but I dont want anyone with the same first and last name in a group twice as that person can very well be in the database twice (they'd have a different partner)

so I have this code:
       (I'll be using this in djnago admin as an action)

Model:

```
class people(models.Model)
   fname = models.CharField()
   lname = models.CharField()
   group = models.IntegerField()
   partner = model.CharField()
```

View:

```
   N = 4
   Num = randint(0, N-1)
   for x in queryset:
       x.group = Num
       (if group == group & fname == fname & lname == lname:)<--Thats the part I am confused about, how can I check to see if these fields are the same, if they are, I want to change the group number field)
           x.group = (Num + 1) % N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Unique Together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together). Change Your Model as below

```
class people(models.Model)
    fname = models.CharField()
    lname = models.CharField()
    group = models.IntegerField()
    partner = model.CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('fname', 'lname', 'group',)
```

Comment: How would I apply it to my code above under x.group = Num followed by (if !unique_togther) ?